# Which model(s) are appropriate for this kind of data

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, modeling, dataset, fitting

So, I tried to implement a model on some data. The dependent variable is a ratio that can get higher than 1, is lower bounded by zero and, seeing figure 1, is left skewed.Thus, a logit regression is out of the picture.
The independent variables exist of the hours an individual performed some task. There are a lot of zero data points in the independent variables, as you can see in figure 1.

[image: Pairs panel of dependent and independents variables(1)]

The problem is that I tried to implement an OLS regression, with all the predictors. Consequently, I needed to perform transformations, because of heteroscedasticity and non-normal residuals, as seen in figure 2. But doing this with variables that are heavily zero-inflated seems rather impossible.

Can someone pinpoint me in some direction that could work? Maybe a model that is better suited for this kind of data or I'm interpreting things in the wrong way?

[image: Residuals plot (2)]